# Eager Loading Validation in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, validation, laravel-4

I am having some trouble figuring out how to validate that an entire eager loaded query is valid before going on with my order of operations.

```
public function subIndex($box, $variant) {

  $boxes = Boxes::where('planId', '=', 1)
           ->where('handle', '=', $box)
           ->with(array('variants' => function($query) use ($variant) {
             $query->where('handle', '=', $variant)->with('products');
            }))->first();

  if($boxes) {

    return View::make('checkout.select', array('boxes' => $boxes));

  }

  return Redirect::to('/');

}
```

It seems that the closure's result is irrelevant to the if check. Thus resulting in "Undefined offset:" errors in my view.

If the "box" is invalid, the error occurs, but if the closure's query is invalid, it will still fire off. I know there are 2 queries being created here, but am unsure on how to check if the second query was valid.

Am I being too greedy with trying to minimize my queries when it comes to validation?

Comment: I "fixed" it by simply adding a isset($boxes->variants[0]) in the if check.

Answer (score 0):

I kept the same eager loading code and added isset to the if check.

```
if(isset($boxes->variants[0])) {

  return View::make('checkout.select', array('boxes' => $boxes));

}
```